# What is the best way to call C/C++ code from other languages such as Java, PHP, Perl, Python, etc?

Tags: java, c++, c, perl

What is the best way to call C/C++ from other languages such as Java, Python, Perl, PHP, etc?

Answer (score 10):

### From Perl

[Inline::C](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Inline::C)
[Inline::CPP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Inline::CPP)
[Inline::Java](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Inline::Java)
[Inline::Python](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Inline::Python)
[Inline::Lua](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Inline::Lua)

excerpt from [Inline::C-Cookbook](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Inline/C/C-Cookbook.pod):

```
use Inline C => <<'END_C';

  void greet() {
    printf("Hello, world\n");
  }
END_C

greet;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use Swig, it allows you to generate code for multiple languages that calls any C/C++ functions.
http://www.swig.org/

Comment: So, in the minute that passed between you asking and answering your own question, you downloaded swig, played around with it and found it to be a good solution to your problem domain?

Comment: @kasperjj: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572/is-it-poor-etiquette-to-answer-your-own-question

Comment: Cool... was not aware of this :-)

Comment: unfortunately, swig not always works as expected, especially on "strange" unices like AIX

Answer (score 3):

That really depends on the language... some languages can bind directly to c/c++ libraries, others such as java needs to have explicit interfaces written. If you are trying to solve a specific problem, I would suggest that you provide more details about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

It's going to depend on the language and what sort of integration you want.

All of those languages will let you execute an system command, so you could build your C into an executable, and invoke it like a command.  In Python:

```
os.system("myccode -v args etc")
```

The downside of this method is that you don't share any memory state, or return much information, and you have the overhead of spinning up a process.  On the plus side, it's usable everywhere, and very low-tech.

Each language has their own mechanism for invoking C within the same process.  Python for example has C API, and you can build your C code into a Python extension.  This allows for a very tight integration, but is more work, both in learning the C API, and in carefully writing the code to not leak memory.

Python also provides [ctypes](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/module-ctypes.html), which can invoke C DLLs.  This is a bit easier than a full C extension, but doesn't provide all the same opportunities for integration.